# Getting the home tile rearranging effect in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a `ListBox` with items that I'd like the user to be able to re-arrange, in a similar fashion to how the tiles on the home screen can be re-arranged. Is there a control or some easy way to implement it, or will I have to roll it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to roll this yourself. At this stage there has not been a control released that implements this out of the box.

Comment: Yes -- it's very frustrating.  I got half an implementation up and running on the emulator, but when I tried it on a physical device it was too slow.  First one to release an open source implementation of this type of control get a LOT of kudos!